# Gnome (Ubuntu): how to programmatically bring a program window to the background? (behind anothers windows)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, gnome

From a custom bash script, I open several terminal (via the command gnome-terminal). Then, at the end, I open a specific terminal (it executes a specific command) and I am looking for a way to programmatically move this terminal behind all other terminal I opened before via my script.

How Can I do that ? I take a look in xdotool package but I didn't find any option for "bring to background"..

Edit : the goal => I want create a special animation for a presentation ;) Ill open several terminal (via bash script) for cover all the screen, then Ill open a special terminal but it must be not visible (its hidden behind others terminals) and when Ill close terminals , I want see the special terminal. This is why I want find a way for open a terminal and, Immediately, "move" this terminal behind all others.

Comment: Why do you open in it in a terminal then? Why not run it in the background of the main script.

Comment: because I want create a special animation for a presentation ;) Ill open several terminal (via bash script) for cover all the screen, then Ill open a special terminal but it must be not visible (its hidden behind others terminals) and when Ill close terminals , I want see the special terminal. This is why I want find a way for open a terminal and, Immediately, "move" this terminal behind all others.